# Item template is not nesting my files

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2017

This is my *.vstemplate

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>Form.xaml</DefaultName>
    <Name>Mapaz Form</Name>
    <Description>Mapaz form.</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
    <ShowByDefault>false</ShowByDefault>
    <TemplateGroupID>WPF</TemplateGroupID>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="Designer" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.xaml" ReplaceParameters="true">Form.xaml</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.xaml.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Form.xaml.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$Resources.resx" ReplaceParameters="true">Resources.resx</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$Resources.Designer.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Resources.Designer.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$Resources.da.resx" ReplaceParameters="true">Resources.da.resx</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$Resources.sv.resx" ReplaceParameters="true">Resources.sv.resx</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$Resources.zh-CHS.resx" ReplaceParameters="true">Resources.zh-CHS.resx</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

The problem is that *Resources.Designer.cs is not nested under *Resources.resx.
VisualStudio is nesting *.xaml.cs under *.xaml so I don't know why the other one is not working as inteded.

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. For anybody who encounters the same problem this is the solution.

```
<ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$Resources.resx\$fileinputname$Resources.Designer.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">Resources.Designer.cs</ProjectItem>
```

So the answer is to literally nest it under the *.resx file you want which is in our case the invariant one.